# How can I parse an array with relevant data on the next line

Tags: perl, parsing, nested-loops, san

open my $outfile, '>', $outpath or $logger->logdie("Error: Can't open $outpath. It may be open.:$!");I have  a command whose output is read into an array (split by newline) and then parsed. 
It worked perfectly when I used to slurp it from a file and just use local $/ = "";. but I read that having an intermediary file is wasteful, and changed it. now I can't read the next line at all!!!
here are the different types of data output needing to be parsed:

```
fcalias name DA540_MAE_I0032 vsan 24
pwwn X0:00:00:63:ab:03:86:e1

fcalias name NAEMS02_DH6_AUX0 vsan 53

fcalias name NRTMF02_DM3_BE0 vsan 53

fcalias name DMSRT56-777_09C0 vsan 53
interface fc2/33 swwn 20:13:ev:0d:ed:3e:da:00
```

when pwwn appears, I want it added to the fcalias, with variable "type" = pwwn/swwn/none depending on the data.

here's my code,

```
sub fcalias 
   { my ($path, $commandfile, $switch_ip, @data) = @_;
     my $outpath = "$path${switch_ip}_${commandfile}.csv";  
     open my $outfile, '>', $outpath or $logger->logdie("Error: Can't open $outpath. It   may be open.:$!");    
     my ($type, $fcalias, $vsan);

     while  (@data) 
    { $_ = shift(@data); 
      s/^\s+//;       # Delete leading whitespaces
      next if (/^$/); # Skip empty lines

      if  (/^fcalias name (\S+) vsan (\S+)/) 
         {($fcalias, $vsan) = ($1, $2);next;} 

      elsif (/^pwwn (\S+)/) 
           {$type = "pwwn"; my $pwwn = $1; 
            print ($outfile, "$fcalias;$vsan;$type;$pwwn;;;$switch_ip\n");
           } 

      elsif  (/interface (\S+) swwn (\S+)/) 
            {$type = "interface"; 
            my ($interface,$swwn) = ($1,$2); 
            print ($outfile, "$fcalias;$vsan;$type;;$swwn;$interface;$switch_ip\n");
            } 

      else  {$type = "none";
            print ($outfile, "$fcalias;$vsan;$type;;;;$switch_ip\n");
           # print "$_ \n";
            }
    }
    print "..................DONE\n";
}
```

of course as you might have noticed, the else doesnt work at all, I get fcalias doubles.  but no matter what I try, I can't add get the output I need. This subroutine is part of a bigger script which has been optimized and is just missing this part.....Help!

for reference, here's the old code loop. please excuse  the long post and code formatting. I tried.  Thanks!

```
local $/ = "";
while (<DATA>) 
{ if  ($_ =~ m/^fcalias name (\S+) vsan (\S+)\s+pwwn (\S+)/) 
     { my ($fcalias, $vsan, $pwwn) = ($1, $2, $3);
       my $type = "pwwn";
       print (OUTFILE "$fcalias;$vsan;$type;$pwwn;;;$switch_ip\n");  
      } 

  elsif  ($_ =~ m/^fcalias name (\S+) vsan (\S+)\s+interface (\S+) swwn (\S+)/) 
      { my ($fcalias, $vsan, $interface, $swwn) = ($1, $2, $3 ,$4);
        my $type = "interface"; 
        print (OUTFILE "$fcalias;$vsan;$type;;$interface;$swwn;$switch_ip\n");
       } 

  else  ($_ =~ m/^fcalias name (\S+) vsan (\S+)/) 
       { my ($fcalias, $vsan) = ($1, $2);
         my $type = "none";
         print (OUTFILE "$fcalias;$vsan;$type;;;;$switch_ip\n");
       }
}
```

Comment: Your indentation is atrocious. Why make things so hard for yourself?

Comment: Spent 20 minutes trying to mess with the formatting on this page. it wouldn't take as it was... First post, but I think I fixed it up now, beware the TAB button!, lol.

Comment: Thanks for the help though. Really.  Without you, I could never have fixed this problem.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question in the title, you either

1. Look ahead to the next line, or
2. Patch the result of reading the previous line, when you read the next one.

Of the `else` not working at all, are you aware that you've commented half of it out?  And that it doesn't write to OUTFILE ?  *And that none of your provided input will reach it?*  You're skipping empty lines and matching every other line.  Perform the body of the else when you match ^fcalias (or run out of data) and find that the variables it sets have not been reset; also, reset those variables in the pwwn|interface cases.

To avoid an intermediary file but still use your older code, use open with a pipe.  E.g.,

```
open DATA, "fcalias-stuff |" or die $!;
```

Comment: 1. I'm going to try to convert the array to a string and see if it will slurp the oI can't believe I didn't think about it...
2. I'm aware of that, I wanted to see the output on the screen and see just what was going into the loop, but it was duplicating values, I edited it out to lessen confusion, and I'll try your suggestion tomorrow morning thanks!

Comment: tried  
 open (DATA, "$data |") or die $!;
 local $/ = "";
 while (<DATA>)
but got this error. 
sh: line 1: pwwn: command not found
this error iterates over 150 lines.. 

I don't want to use DATA, I want to use the array I have (data array split with \n)  and patch the result of reading the previous line. my problem is that some of the data lines have nothing before. (see sample data...)

Comment: @Comocho00 That code is [fine](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html).  You have a problem elsewhere, or with the contents of `$data`.

Answer (score 1):

If reading the data line by line makes your work much harder, why do you it? The issue with slurping is that everything ends up in memory at once. If you file is small enough this should not be a problem.

An additional comment on your style. You should not use global file handles (`OUTFILE`). These are global variables with all the issues that come with them. If you have an open with global file handle in a recursive function e.g. you will always close and reopen the file handle.

Better use local file handles as in `open my $outfile, '>', $outpath or die`.

Comment: It works for the rest of the subs, this is the only one giving me trouble. I do split the data into an array before sending it to the sub, so I'll try sending the unsplit data instead.....memory isn't that much of a problem. (the  file isn't that large) although speed is, thanks for the tips, I edited the script to update the output and I'll try it tomorrow!

Comment: sending original unsplit data didn't work at all.  just got use of uninitialized values.